# how to prevent singleton object creation?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, singleton

I have singleton class like below.

```
class X {

    static let shared = X()
}
```

If i try to create object for singleton like below

```
let y = X()
```

I need to throw an error like you can't create object for singleton.

Comment: The simplest way is to declare `private init() { }`.

Comment: make it's default constructor or init() to be private

Comment: @Paulw11 or `fileprivate`.

Comment: Yes, it depends whether you want your singleton to be final

Comment: @Paulw11 can you post class

Comment: literally add `private init() { }` or `fileprivate init() {}` to what you already have

Comment: just to clarify you don't have a singleton implemented in your code you have a shared instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class X {

    static let shared = X()
    private init() { }
}

let b = X() // wrong . 'X' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

let c = X.shared // right
```